# Powershell how to escape regex pipe in npx parameter

Tags: windows, powershell, npx

I'm trying to execute npx command containing pipe in regex parameter:

```
npx depcruise --exclude 'node_modules"|"test' --output-type dot src
```

But I'm getting error:

```
'test' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I tried all combinations described here https://octopus.com/blog/powershell-pipe-escaping but none works. Whats is the correct way to escape pipe in such command?

Comment: Doesn't `'node_modules|test'` work? What do you need to escape `|` for?

Comment: 'node_modules|test' dosen't work - same error

Comment: Assumed you run this command line in a PowerShell console you could try the *stop parsing* parameter to prevent PowerShell to interpret your arguments as PowerShell cmdlet parameters ...  `npx --% depcruise --exclude "node_modules|test" --output-type dot src`

Comment: Didn't work. Still the same error

Comment: @Kamui am running into the same error, did you find a solution in the meantime?